# How to parse and sort JSON with multiple keys in Python

Tags: python, json

Actually training with JSON trying to understand how I can parse a new JSON using two differents keys. I want to sort some logs for data vizualisation purpose.

My data JSON

```
{
            "productTitle": "Product",
            "apiName": "soapwebservice"
            "statusCode": "200 OK"
},
{
            "productTitle": "Product",
            "apiName": "productionservice",
            "statusCode": "200 OK"
},
{
            "productTitle": "Product",
            "apiName": "firstapi",
            "statusCode": "200 OK"
},          
{
            "productTitle": "Product",
            "apiName": "firstapi",
            "statusCode": "200 OK"
}, 
{
            "productTitle": "Suitability",
            "apiName": "suitability-api",
            "statusCode": "200 OK"
}
```

The Output JSON expected :

```
{
    "Product": 4,
    "api-activity": {
         "soapwebservice": 1,
         "productionservice": 1,
         "firstapi": 2
    }
}
{
    "Suitability": 1,
    "api-activity": {
         "suitability-api": 1,
    }
}
```

This is my first code to parse and count the first key :

```
import json
from collections import Counter

with open('events1.json') as json_data:
    json_obj = json.load(json_data) # Read the JSON file

    # print(json_obj['calls'][0]['appName']); #Example JSON Extract
    c = Counter(player['productTitle'] for player in json_obj['calls'])

with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(c, indent=4)) # Parse and write the file

print("Translation of JSON");
```

I'm looking for a way to obtain the expected JSON, probably with a loop as explain here : [parse JSON values by multilevel keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445791/parse-json-values-by-multilevel-keys][1]) 
But I cannot obtain the JSON as expected, do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the elements by desired properties. First group by product title, and in each resulting group, group the elements once again, but now by api name. The desired counters are just the amounts of elements in each resulting group:

```
import itertools
import json

def by_product_title(data):
    return data['productTitle']

def by_api_name(data):
    return data['apiName']

json_str = '''
[
    {
        "productTitle": "Product",
        "apiName": "soapwebservice",
        "statusCode": "200 OK"
    },
    {
        "productTitle": "Product",
        "apiName": "productionservice",
        "statusCode": "200 OK"
    },
    ...
]
'''

data = json.loads(json_str)
grouped_by_product_title = itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=by_product_title), by_product_title)
for product, group in grouped_by_product_title:
    elements = list(group)
    grouped_by_api_name = itertools.groupby(sorted(elements, key=by_api_name), by_api_name)
    api_activity = {key: len(list(val)) for key, val in grouped_by_api_name}
    output = {product: len(elements), 'api-activity': api_activity}
    json_output = json.dumps(output, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(json_output)
```

Output:

```
{
    "Product": 4,
    "api-activity": {
        "firstapi": 2,
        "productionservice": 1,
        "soapwebservice": 1
    }
}
{
    "Suitability": 1,
    "api-activity": {
        "suitability-api": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. In my case, and as I use a JSON file, I have to call it with json.load and not json.loads just in case somebody try your code too.

Comment: Nice example of multi-level groupby with itertools.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this. Check it out.

```
import json

json_str = """
[
{
            "productTitle": "Product",
            "apiName": "soapwebservice",
            "statusCode": "200 OK"
},
{
            "productTitle": "Product",
            "apiName": "productionservice",
            "statusCode": "200 OK"
},
{
            "productTitle": "Product",
            "apiName": "firstapi",
            "statusCode": "200 OK"
},
{
            "productTitle": "Product",
            "apiName": "firstapi",
            "statusCode": "200 OK"
},
{
            "productTitle": "Suitability",
            "apiName": "suitability-api",
            "statusCode": "200 OK"
}
]
"""

data_set = json.loads(json_str)
data_list = []
for data in data_set:
    title = data["productTitle"]
    exist = False
    for existing_data in data_list:
        if title in existing_data:
            exist = True
            existing_data[title] += 1
            if data["apiName"] in existing_data["api-activity"]:
                existing_data["api-activity"][data["apiName"]] += 1
            else:
                existing_data["api-activity"][data["apiName"]] = 1
    if not exist:
        new = dict()
        new[data["productTitle"]] = 1
        new["api-activity"] = dict()
        new["api-activity"][data["apiName"]] = 1
        data_list.append(new)

print(json.dumps(data_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that json.load (and json.loads) will only take one element from the file. To Fix this you need to convert it to a list.

```
[
  {
    "productTitle": "Product",
    "apiName": "soapwebservice",
    "statusCode": "200 OK"
  },
  {
    "productTitle": "Product",
    "apiName": "productionservice",
    "statusCode": "200 OK"
  },
  {
    "productTitle": "Product",
    "apiName": "firstapi",
    "statusCode": "200 OK"
  },
  {
    "productTitle": "Product",
    "apiName": "firstapi",
    "statusCode": "200 OK"
  },
  {
    "productTitle": "Suitability",
    "apiName": "suitability-api",
    "statusCode": "200 OK"
  }
]
```

Your second problem is that you are trying to access json_obj['calls'] which does not exist. By removing the accessor you get the following code:

```
import json
from collections import Counter

with open('events1.json') as json_data:
    json_obj = json.load(json_data) # Read the JSON file
    c = Counter(player['productTitle'] for player in json_obj)

with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(c, indent=4)) # Parse and write the file

print("Translation of JSON");
```

This results in the following output in output.json:

```
{
  "Product": 4, 
  "Suitability": 1
}
```